# Error while opening "configure app urls" in central admin sp2013

Tags: central-administration, app

App Management Service & Microsoft Sharepoint Foundation Subscription Service are running but it still shows error as follows.
Error message :

> Settings or services required to complete this request are not
>   currently available.  Try this operation again later.  If the problem
>   persists, contact your administrator.

Error in sharepoint log viewer :

> Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException: Settings or services required to
>   complete this request are not currently available.  Try this operation
>   again later.  If the problem persists, contact your administrator.
>
> at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSubscriptionSettingsServiceApplicationProxy.ProcessCommonExceptions(Exception
>   ex, SPServiceLoadBalancerContext context)     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSubscriptionSettingsServiceApplicationProxy.ExecuteOnChannel(CodeBlock
>   codeBlock)     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSubscriptionSettingsServiceApplicationProxy.GetSubscriptionMetadata(Guid
>   subscriptionId)     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSiteSubscriptionSettingsManager.GetMetadata(SPSiteSubscriptionIdentifier
>   subscriptionIdentifier)     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationPages.ConfigureAppSettingsPage.OnLoad(EventArgs
>   e)     at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()     at
>   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean
>   includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)

Comment: I also faced the same issue after i reboot the server. when i try to access Setup APP URL always shows Settings or services required to complete this request are not currently available. Try this operation again later. If the problem persists, contact your administrator. could you give me some advise thanks/

Comment: Hi, I am also facing the same issue. Can you please provide me the solution if you have already resolved the issue or found any work around ? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

This error is due one of the service application not running in your machine.

1. App Management Service Application
2. Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Subscription Settings Service Application
3. Managed Metadata Service

This should resolve the issue, because just now I resolved the issue in my Development environment.

Answer (score 1):

you need to give permissions to the App Management Service Application and  Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Subscription Settings Service Application

- Select the App Management Service Application
- Permissions in the Ribbon add the user name
- Select the Subscription Settings Service Application
- Permissions in the Ribbon add the user name
- and now go to CA
- APPS
- Configure App URLs

that did the trick for me .....